# Sharing a Google Sheet that has Script

Tags: google-sheets

I am a teacher preparing for distance learning. Google Forms are awesome, but they have some limitations. I created an old school google form with google sheets to get around a few issues I was having. I used the script from [this data entry form](https://www.bpwebs.com/how-to-create-a-data-entry-form-in-google-sheet/)

It works great! ...but I'm worried my students won't use it since they will get a warning that says "This app isn't verified." I know for a fact that my students will not click on the "advanced" button to authorize the app.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*This screen can't be removed without app verification.*

#### More Information:

As per the [unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) page:

> An unverified app is an app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive apps.

It's designed this way to stop tricky people with tricky apps blindsiding people by getting them to approve sensitive scopes without too much thought.

Unless you want to verify your app, which will need to be done through the GCP console (instructions on verification can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)), your only way around this is to just tell your students to click on the "advanced" button to authorise the app.

**Side note:** Verification is not required for Apps Script projects whose owner and users belong to the same G Suite domain or customer.

#### Further Reading:

- [Google Cloud Platform Projects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)

#### References:

- [Unverified apps - Google Cloud Platform Console Help](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)
- [OAuth Client Verification | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)